# Std thread detach

Tags: c++, std

Having this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

void new_thread(int n) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(n));
    std::cout << "New thread - exiting!\n";
}

int main() {    
    std::thread (new_thread, 5).detach();
    std::cout << "Main thread - exiting!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible for the `new_thread` not to be automatically terminated by the main thread and to do it's work - outputs `New thread - exiting!` after 5 secs?

I'm NOT mean the case of `join` when the main thread waits for a child, but for the main thread to detach the spawned thread and terminates leaving the new thread doing it's work?

Comment: What do you expect `detach` does?

Comment: What you described is more similar to `join` than `detach`. `detach` is like "I won't care about the thread anymore, I won't wait it to finish"

Comment: When the application terminates, all threads desist.

Comment: @Eljay I've updated my question. Can You be so nice and answer it now?

Comment: Your new question cannot be done with a thread.  It can be done with a `fork`, but that's OS dependent.

Comment: On some operating systems (like Linux) all threads are terminated when the main thread exits. On other operating systems (like Windows) threads can keep running after the main thread terminates. The C++ standard doesn't specify what should happen to child threads when the main process terminates - that's implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[basic.start.main]/5** A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control flows off the end of the *compound-statement* of `main`, the effect is equivalent to a `return` with operand 0.

> **[support.start.term]/9**
> `[[noreturn]] void exit(int status);`
> *Effects:*
> ...
>
> - Finally, control is returned to the host environment.

You seem to expect that when `main` returns, the program waits for all threads to finish - in effect, implicitly joins all detached threads. That's not what happens - instead, the program terminates, and the operating system cleans up resources allocated to the process (including any threads).

Comment: I've updated my question. Can You be so nice and answer it now?

Comment: Again - once `main` returns, `exit` is called, and the process is terminated; nothing in it runs anymore. If you want the second thread to finish, `main` must continue to run until it finishes. The easiest way to achieve that is for `main` to `join` the second thread, rather than `detach` it. In what way does this obvious, straightforward solution fail to meet your requirements? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`detach`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) on a thread means that you don't care about what the thread does any more. If that thread doesn't finish executing before the program ends (when `main` returns), then you won't see its effects.

However, if the calling thread is around long enough for the detached thread to complete, then you will see the output. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4fT38j).

Comment: Ok, but what's going on with such detached thread? Why doesn't it run as separated "program" and prints?

Comment: Nothing happens with that thread. As far as the program is concerned, that thread disappears. If there are any resources to be cleaned up, the OS will do that.

Comment: So when the main, calling thread is finished the  called thread is destroyed automatically with all it's resources that's why we get no output from that child thread?

Comment: I've updated my question. Can You be so nice and answer it now?

Answer (score 0):

`detach` separates your thread from the main thread. You want to use `join()`

> Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing
> execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be
> freed once the thread exits.
>
> ```
> After calling detach *this no longer owns any thread.
> ```

From [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach)

Comment: You said: "allowing execution to continue independently" BUT when the main, calling tread finish the spawned thread is also killed?